# Why is herring used for tikun?

Tags: food, fish, repentance-teshuvah

Many people have the practice, on the yahrzeit of (especially) a parent, of bringing food to the synagogue so that others might recite *b'rachos* (benedictions) over eating the food after *shacharis*, which are meant to benefit the deceased. They call this food *tikun n'shama*, or just *tikun*.

It seems that the most common foods offered as *tikun* (in my experience in several Orthodox synagogues) are drinks, egg *kichel*, batter cake, and herring. Why herring?

- It's relatively expensive (certainly when compared to the *kichel* and batter cake).
- If the idea is to promote the recitation of *b'rachos*, herring doesn't help, as it shares *b'rachos* (fore- and after-) with the drinks.
- Although it's tasty<sup>[1]</sup>, I don't think it will be missed terribly if absent. Herring without a drink or *kichel* would cause people to seek something to wash down the herring; *kichel* and a drink without herring is perfectly palatable and Part Of Your Complete Breakfast.

So why herring?

---

<sup>[1] YMMV.</sup>

Comment: Maybe it's Jewish Soul Food. :)

Comment: why is simply being tasty not good of enough of a reason? You could ask why any other specific food also. Herring has been culturally a part of Jewish foods for a long time now so seems fitting to be part of an event which involves food.

Comment: @Dude why Jewish food "Lightly salted herring is a very popular traditional dish not only in Russia, but also in Holland, Sweden, Germany, Denmark and some other northern countries. "

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2274&st=&pgnum=167 R YE Henkin writes that the food served at Shul on a Yahrtzeit derives from the original practice of having a Talmid Chakham deliver words of Torah and then having a Seudat Mitzva. (He then complains about people who just do the food part.) Perhaps (my speculation) fish is/was the cheapest form of meat to bring to the Seudat Mitzva (like we see some people insist on for a Siyum).

Comment: One person did it, and then everybody copied it? (And the original Halacha is to fast on a parent's Yahrzeit, not to participate in a party of any sort. Just BTW.)

Comment: @msh210 What is batter cake?

Comment: @SAH, cake made from batter

Comment: @msh210 i think every cake is made from batter?

Comment: @SAH, no, many are made from dough

Comment: @msh210 I bake a lot and have never heard of such a thing.(as "batter cake," or as a cake made from dough, for that matter). Could it be that they were saying "butter cake"?

Comment: @SAH, I don't know who "they" are: I wrote this post myself. And I didn't mean "batter cake" as a _thing_: I simply meant a cake made of batter. There are certainly cakes made of dough rather than batter.

Comment: @msh210 Can you show me a picture of a batter cake? I'm genuinely interested, particularly if this is some sort of a traditional Jewish food.

Comment: @SAH let's continue this in [chat], shall we?

Answer (score 6):

This is not a definite reason, but it may be in memory of the teaching of Rav Yehuda said in the name of Rav found in [Bava Bathra 74b](http://halakhah.com/bababathra/bababathra_74.html#PARTb) which talks about the Leviathan that was salted and stored away by HaShem for the Tzaddikim in the world to come, meaning after the resurrection of the dead. There will be a special meal which will include salted fish.

It would be suggesting that soul will be resurrected and included in that meal.

Comment: Wow. This may be a backsplanation, but it's a very good backsplanation. May this meme spread as far as the fishy meme it applies to, and may we all enjoy Leviathan meat together speedily, in our days.

Comment: Interesting. Nothing like salted fillet of "soul" :-)

Comment: +1 nice. I was thinking the same thing than scrolled down to see this. But as Isaac says this is cute in retrospect, I highly doubt the hassidic rebbes had a meeting about what to serve at a tikun and decided on this remez:)

Comment: They could have salted any fish, see my answer

Comment: Is Leviathan a fish?? I thought it was a "sea monster: and maybe it's considered a mammal like whales.

Comment: @DanF There are many different explanations of Leviathan. All of them are true. One of those is that this fish, with fins and scales will be a part of Moshiach's seudah after the resurrection. It is at that time that the chiddush of using its fin to ritually slaughter the Shor HaBor will be introduced. (Something which currently isn't done.) The Lubavitcher Rebbe emphasized in his talks many times that this is a literal, physical meal that will take place.

Answer (score 3):

You can read [this article](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/recipe/herring-and-onions/) in full, but I’ll just quote the important part below.

> Most likely, the fish became popular among Eastern European Jews for practical reasons: **it was cheap.**

—————
*some edits*

Based on some of the comments I’d like to add some clarification. Although [Yaakov Dean’s answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67214/16706) is quite clever, it does not attempt to explain why herring was used, because they could have (in his scenario) salted any fish of their choosing. (Refer to my answer above on why they chose herring.)

As for the original question, the points raised are quite valid ones, and this is a very fair question. And it makes sense to question all things, and determine their sources.

Going on the information that herring was cheap, that would mean that it was ever cheaper than anything else in this context. (Including that which was mentioned in the question.)

Using some reasoning however, I would conclude that based on that which I said above, there aren’t any other *hidden* reasons to the fish. Similarly as is found by the Shtreimel. It was cold back in Europe. As is quoted from the [Shtreimel Wikipedia page:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtreimel)

> While there is strong religious custom for Jewish males to cover their heads, from the standpoint of Jewish law **there is no special religious significance to the shtreimel** as compared to other head coverings. However, the wearing of two head coverings is considered to add additional spiritual merit, plus the presence of beautiful craftsmanship adds beautification and honor to the custom.

You may note on that page, that later on someone added on additional symbolism, but that was not the original intention.

And I do believe that this is the same situation present by herring. Even though now it may not be economical, it certainly was. And there may even be extra symbolism added on for good measure.

*plus it’s tasty.*

Comment: Another more profane thing is that Russians like to eat herrings when drinking vodka.

Comment: I hear Russians like to drink vodka while eating.

Comment: I kind of deal with this in the question already. Yes, herring was cheap compared to other meats or fishes (let's say), but surely it's not cheap compared to nothing or to more kichel.

Comment: The original reason was that it was cheap and they needed something to eat. Now it’s a minhag. Similar thing by the shtreimal, it was cold. Now its the minhag.

Comment: @Shmuel Russians like to drink vodka whenever they can, but it's a special "side dish" for vodka. A similar thing from Poland: http://www.thenews.pl/1/12/Artykul/165043,Polish-herring-and-vodka-consumption-fall-together

Comment: Even today, herring is relatively cheaper than most other fish. It seems that it also preserves well and perhaps because of its small size, was easy to catch more of them and store them. Of course, we are familiar with salted salmon and whitefish. These are significantly more costly and take up much more space.